# Grails tag actionSubmit causes 404 error

Tags: java, forms, grails, http-status-code-404

I'm using the grails tags `form` and `actionSubmit` and I'm getting a 404 error when submit (I am using Grails 2.3.7).

At view `write.gsp`:

```
<g:form action="send">
    <g:actionSubmit value="test1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="test2"/>
</g:form>
```

and when the view is rendered, it results in:

```
<form method="post" action="/messaging/send">
    <input type="submit" value="test1" name="_action_test1">
    <input type="submit" value="test2">
</form>
```

At controller:

```
class MessagingController {
   def send = {
      //some code here
      chain(action:"read")
   }

   def read = {
      // more working code
   }

}
```

So, if I click at button test2, it works and the "read" view is rendered, but if I click at test1 button, I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /messaging/send
type Status report
message /messaging/send
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Why actionSubmit is not working propertly?

My suspicions are that is related to the autogenerated `name="_action_test1"` because if I remove the underscore (i.e. using firebug) it works.

But according to Grails documentation the tag usage is ok:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing action field from actionSubmit:

`<!--label derived from message bundle-->
<g:actionSubmit value="${message(code:'label.update')}" action="Update" />`

`<g:actionSubmit value="test1" action="test1"/>`

Used it recently in a plugin ripped straight out of generated grails code: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/views/jsshadmin/_edit.gsp which works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @vahid, your aproach of including the action works (but I don't understand why because action is already defined at form tag):

    <g:actionSubmit action="send" value="test1"/>

What I do not understand is why in the documentation it is said that action parameter is optional...

Comment: yes it can seem rather confusing, just think of it in a different way if you declare actionSubmit then in the specific form you can apply multiple actions that work with that same form exactly like you would see in scaffolding view of edit/delete. If you wanted a form that did a single action with its results you could use  <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" /> this would then the defined action of the form... I hope it makes more sense